# I have to click twice a link button to change page

Tags: asp.net

I have to click linkbutton twice to change the page and load subfolders of current folder. I think I have some problems with my session and event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            TableRow r = new TableRow();
            TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
            LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
            var strarray = Server.MapPath(Session["url"].ToString()).Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
            Table table = new Table();
            l.ID = "lable" + table.Rows.Count;
            l.Text = strarray.Last();
            l.EnableViewState = true;
            r.ID = "newRow" + table.Rows.Count;
            c1.ID = "newC1" + table.Rows.Count;
            c1.Controls.Add(l);
            r.Cells.Add(c1);
            table.Rows.Add(r);
            this.form1.Controls.Add(table);
        }
        else
        {
            if(Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(Session["url"].ToString())))
            {
                string[] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath(Session["url"].ToString()));
                Table table = new Table();
                foreach (string str in allFolders)
                {
                    TableRow r = new TableRow();
                    TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
                    LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
                    var strarray = str.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                    l.ID = strarray.Last();
                    l.CommandName = "createLink";
                    l.Click+= new EventHandler(LinkButton_Command);
                    l.Text = strarray.Last();
                    l.EnableViewState = true;                  
                    r.ID = "newRow" + table.Rows.Count;
                    c1.ID = "newC1" + table.Rows.Count;
                    c1.Controls.Add(l);
                    r.Cells.Add(c1);
                    table.Rows.Add(r);
                    this.form1.Controls.Add(table);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Work work=new Work();
                work.SetFolder(Session["url"].ToString());
                work.CreateFolder();
            }
        }
    }

    public void LinkButton_Command(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["url"] = Session["url"] + "\\" + ((LinkButton)sender).ID;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because the `Page_Load()` method is called before the `LinkButton_Command()`. The session variable `Session["url"]` still contains the previous value when the code in `Page_Load()` executes.

Try moving the code from the else-branch of `Page_Load()` at the end of `LinkButton_Command()`.

Comment: i need to check session in every page load to load directories. i think that is not my issue

Answer (score 0):

after mix up your answer and my program , come to a answer that will work.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(Session["url"].ToString())))
            {
                string[] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath(Session["url"].ToString()));
                Table table = new Table();
                foreach (string str in allFolders)
                {
                    TableRow r = new TableRow();
                    TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
                    LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
                    var strarray = str.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                    l.ID = strarray.Last();
                    l.CommandName = "createLink";
                    l.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Command);
                    l.Text = strarray.Last();
                    l.EnableViewState = true;
                    r.ID = "newRow" + table.Rows.Count;
                    c1.ID = "newC1" + table.Rows.Count;
                    c1.Controls.Add(l);
                    r.Cells.Add(c1);
                    table.Rows.Add(r);
                    this.form1.Controls.Clear();
                    this.form1.Controls.Add(table);
                }
            }

```
    }
    public void LinkButton_Command(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["url"] = Session["url"] + "\\" + ((LinkButton)sender).ID;

        if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(Session["url"].ToString())))
        {
            string[] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath(Session["url"].ToString()));
            Table table = new Table();
            foreach (string str in allFolders)
            {
                TableRow r = new TableRow();
                TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
                LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
                var strarray = str.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                l.ID = strarray.Last();
                l.CommandName = "createLink";
                l.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Command);
                l.Text = strarray.Last();
                l.EnableViewState = true;
                r.ID = "newRow" + table.Rows.Count;
                c1.ID = "newC1" + table.Rows.Count;
                c1.Controls.Add(l);
                r.Cells.Add(c1);
                table.Rows.Add(r);
                this.form1.Controls.Clear();
                this.form1.Controls.Add(table);
            }
        }

    }
```